# EU Consent dialog not shown

Tags: admob, gdprconsentform

I am trying to use `UserMessagingPlatform` to ask for permission for tracking and the EU GDPR consent. It asks for tracking when running on simulator, but the EU-consent dialog is not showing. What is wrong? I have created both in the Funding Choices in AdMob.

This is on iOS and Swift.

```
    private func requestIDFA() {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
                // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
                self.showConsentInformation()
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

  private func showConsentInformation() {
            let parameters = UMPRequestParameters()
            
            // false means users are not under age.
            parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = false
            let debugSettings = UMPDebugSettings()
            debugSettings.geography = UMPDebugGeography.EEA
            parameters.debugSettings = debugSettings

            UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                with: parameters,
                completionHandler: { error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle the error.
                    } else {
                        // The consent information state was updated.
                        // You are now ready to check if a form is
                        // available.
                        let formStatus = UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.formStatus
                        if formStatus == UMPFormStatus.available {
                            self.loadForm()
                        }
                    }
                })
            
        }
    
    func loadForm() {
        UMPConsentForm.load(
            completionHandler: { form, loadError in
                if loadError != nil {
                    // Handle the error
                } else {
                    // Present the form
                    if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == UMPConsentStatus.required {
                        form?.present(from: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController! as UIViewController, completionHandler: { dimissError in
                            if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus == UMPConsentStatus.obtained {
                                // App can start requesting ads.
                                // initGoogleMobileAds()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think AdMob might have treated emulators as a special case. This is what Google says:

> Emulators do not need to be added to the device id list as they have
> testing enabled by default.

Perhaps it makes sense to try to tweak it with the debug code explained [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/ump/ios/quick-start) under section **Force a geography**

I'm running into another odd issue: my test iPhone located outside of EU is being shown the GDPR form consistently on initial run on fresh installs because somehow the UMP keeps returning consentStatus as "required". I expect it to return "notRequired" but it's not happening. It seems like AdMob is not doing it job detecting whether or not my iPhone is in EU or not.